Failed to load Power App with an integrated automate flow, Error Code 504
I build a Power Apps that has integrated Power Automate flow.  Everything was working perfectly and now I am getting error saying that it's not able to open the Power App for editing with error code 504.  any idea how to resolve this.

I have already tried logout,  close browser even access it from different machine

enter image description here

Logout
Open app in different browser.
-Accessing it from different machine


Maybe this app with that flow is too big and became unresponsive: https://sharepains.com/2019/10/10/calling-long-running-flows-in-powerapps . In this case you can download the app, edit the source (for example: cut out the flow part), upload back and try to reopen.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
